# Use Doctrine UUID in prePersist LifecycleCallback

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there any way to use the previous generated UUID in entities LifecycleCallback?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table("user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=36)
     */
    private $slug;

    [.. getId() / setSlug() / getSlug() ..]

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function onPrePersist()
    {
        $this->setSlug($this->getId());
    }
}
```

My intention is to use the UUID as default slug on user creation until I got for example the users name to update the slug. Can be mysql triggers a solution?

Comment: You can use postPersist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have 2 options:

1) You can manually create a UUID through [this library](https://packagist.org/packages/rhumsaa/uuid) (or another library). Then you can access them, in the prePersist event.

2) Or you use the postPersist handler, but this will create an INSERT statement and an UPDATE statement.

Use an MySQL trigger is a bad idea, because nobody can control them. It's like magic, it happens but nobody knows how. And update them is a pain.

Comment: I used option 2) because the additional INSERT statement doesn't matter at this point. Thanx!

Comment: Is it save to create the uuid manually in the constructor? Will such a uuid be overwritten if the entity is loaded from the database?

Comment: Yes it's save to do it. Doctrine skips the constructor if the entity is loaded from the database